# One integral converges if another does?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

What is a continuous function $\phi:[1,\infty) \rightarrow (0,1)$, decreasing to zero for which $$\int_1^\infty \frac{-\phi(t)\log(\phi(t)))}{t}dt$$ diverges, yet

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\phi(t)}{t}dt$$ converges? I have been trying for a while, but I cant find it. Maybe a function like $\log\log\log\log(t)$ or something? But I can't integrate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take $\phi(t)$ in such a way that $\phi(e^u)=\frac{1}{(u+1)\log^2(u+e)}$ we have that
$$ \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\phi(t)}{t}\,dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\phi(e^u)\,du < +\infty $$
while
$$ \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{-\phi(t)\log\phi(t)}{t}\,dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty}-\phi(e^u)\log\phi(e^u)\,du = +\infty$$
by [Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), hence a working choice is
$$ \phi(t) = \color{red}{\frac{1}{(1+\log t)\cdot\log^2(e+\log t)}} $$